# How to make a textbox show the date and time

Tags: c#, textbox

I'm trying to make an app in **C#** which shows the date and time in a textbox.

I want it to show the date and time and automatically update itself when I press the start button and stop updating when I press the stop button. Any idea?

Comment: Have you made the textbox yet?

Comment: What is the point of the user editing the date?  Use a Label.  And a Timer to update its Text property from DateTime.Now.ToString().

Answer (score 2):

Use a timer control. Set its interval property to 1000 and start it in the form_load event. In the timers tick you do the following:

```
textBox.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```